# JQuery Owl-Carousel is not working in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently migrating jQuery-based website template to AngularJS. In the script javascript, I had used $ and jQuery to implement ownCarousel. The script and the front-end HTML works well in normal HTML. But when it comes to AngularJS which I included the script.js in index.html and I copied HTML elements to my view html. The owlCarousel shows nothing, no error at all. Looks like the script.js is stop working. You might want to look the full version of script.js at [here](http://pastebin.com/NWei4LCe).

**Script**

```
if (jQuery("#testimonials-slider").length) {
                jQuery("#testimonials-slider").owlCarousel({
                    singleItem : true,
                    autoHeight : true,
                    mouseDrag: false,
                    transitionStyle : "fade"
                });
            }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-sm-12" data-animation-direction="from-top" data-animation-delay="50">
            <h2 class="section-title">Testimonials</h2>

            <div id="testimonials-slider" class="owl-carousel testimonials">
                <div class="item">
                    <blockquote class="text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elementum libero enim, eget gravida nunc laoreet et. Nullam ac enim auctor, fringilla risus at, imperdiet turpis.</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <div class="col-md-5 center">
                        <div class="author">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/61x61" alt="" />
                            <div>
                                Mark Maecenas<br>
                                <span>CEO at Lorem Ipsum Agency</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <blockquote class="text">
                        <p>Pellentesque elementum libero enim, eget gravida nunc laoreet et. Nullam ac enim auctor, fringilla risus at, imperdiet turpis.</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <div class="col-md-5 center">
                        <div class="author">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/61x61" alt="" />
                            <div>
                                John Doe<br>
                                <span>CTO at Dolor Sit Amet Agency</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <blockquote class="text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elementum libero enim, eget gravida nunc laoreet et. Nullam ac enim auctor, fringilla risus at, imperdiet turpis. Nullam ac enim auctor, fringilla risus at, imperdiet turpis.</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <div class="col-md-5 center">
                        <div class="author">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/61x61" alt="" />
                            <div>
                                Mary Smith<br>
                                <span>UFO at Some Agency</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

**Expected Result**
[image]

**Problem**

> OwnCarousel works well in normal HTML but show nothing with no error when it comes to AngularJS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you should do it in angular way and wrap your code into your custom directive. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive